# Lotus NotesSQL - "Joining" a child document to a parent when querying

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm querying the back end of a customer complaint system build in domino using the NotesSQL driver.

My issue is I have a overall reference for the complaint (agent generated but unique) but there is also a "contact" table (table probably isn't the right word, I'm unfamiliar with Notes terminology) tracking customer calls etc against each complaint.  This table does not have the reference contained it it, so I cannot join in a normal SQL fashion (I believe this is referred to as "application-linked".  Is there anyway (e.g. using Notes implicit fields, etc.) to join these within the SQL query?

Essentially the result required is a record set of the complaint reference with the fields from "contact" against each.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes is not relational. NotesSQL does not support JOIN operations. If there is a parent-child form relationship between your complaint and contact, then you can do a NotesSQL query against multiple forms with the WHERE clause using NoteUNID and NoteRefUNID as described here: [link](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/notessql/3.0.2e/notessql.nsf/abf4ea8c64018c10852563c000646f8f/3e831b4ed597eafb85256dd7004d7efb?OpenDocument). That's the only type of implicit relationship that Notes maintains.

Comment: Thank you, murphy's law dictated that after a couple of hours of messing around and searching, I found that very page five minutes after I posted the question!  Thank you though, I really appreciate the answer regardless.   Interestingly, where there are common fields across views I note you can use the usual explicit join syntax as well.